# How DC offset affects the spectrum of a single pulse

Tags: spectrum

I know that in the magnitude spectrum of a single square DC pulse (0-8V) the lobes are zero at frequencies $$\frac{1}{t},\frac{2}{t},\frac{3}{t},...etc. $$ where t=pulse duration.

If the square pulse goes from -2V to 6V, is the formula for the zero points of the spectrum still the same, ie. $$\frac{n}{t}$$ where n=1,2,3... etc. and t=pulse duration?

What is the difference?

Comment: Grade 1 gobbledegook.

Comment: The amplitude at DC does not affect the amplitude of any of the harmonics.

But the question improperly defines a square wave lobes,.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited it to more coherent form.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I edited the question to more coherent form. OP: Please revert the question to it original form if you wanted something else and add a image of your signals. You should show some own attempt to solve the problem, or you will get voted out!

Comment: A Square wave has null values at even harmonics for f=1/T at 2f, 4f or 2/T, 4/T etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying an offset to a signal will only change a spectrum at DC (frequency of 0Hz).

If the single square pulse goes from 0V to 8V, the value of DC would be \$\mathcal{F}\{ f(t)\}|_{\omega=0}=0\$. If the square wave goes from -2V to 6V, then \$\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}|_{\omega=0}=-2\cdot\delta(0)\$.

Comment: Your original question was about square waves, so I assumed it was periodic. I'll match my answer to your question.